# got an error while trying to deploy Django on railway

Tags: django, railway

i get this error while trying to deploy my Django app on railway (https://i.stack.imgur.com/39h8Q.png)

please has anyone experienced this before, I am new to Django and i do not know where the error is coming from.
please can you help.
and also if there is any other server where  can host the app aside from Heroku